# How to change background color inside <script> tags?

Tags: phpstorm

How do i change the background color inside  tags just like notepad++ does

[image]

I looked up everywhere in the settings, cannot seem to find this

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible:

- JavaScript does not have dedicated style for JavaScript code (e.g. like PHP does)
- You cannot specify custom color for content of specific tag

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1415 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.